# ts.intersect does not work with xts objects

Tags: r, time-series, xts

The following produces an error

```
a1 = as.xts(ts(rnorm(20), start=c(1980,1), freq=4))
a2 = as.xts(ts(rnorm(30), start=c(1983,1), freq=4))
a = ts.intersect(a1,a2)

Error in .cbind.ts(list(...), .makeNamesTs(...), dframe = dframe, union = FALSE) : 
  no time series supplied
```

The documentation says argument should be

two or more univariate or multivariate time series, or objects which can coerced to time series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ts.intersect` determines whether the objects is a `ts` object by looking for the `tsp` attribute. `as.xts.ts` removes the `tsp` attribute, which is why it is not coerced back to a `ts` object.

This looks like a bug in xts->ts->xts conversion, but I need to take a closer look.

As a work-around, you can manually add the `tsp` attribute to your xts object (note that this might cause issues with other xts methods, e.g. `str.xts`) and add a `.tsp` attribute as well.

```
set.seed(21)
A1 <- ts(rnorm(20), start=c(1980,1), freq=4)
A2 <- ts(rnorm(30), start=c(1983,1), freq=4)
# convert to xts
a1 <- as.xts(A1)
a2 <- as.xts(A2)
# add tsp attribute
# (so stats:::.cbind.ts will think these are coercible to ts objects)
tsp(a1) <- tsp(A1)
tsp(a2) <- tsp(A2)
# add .tsp attribute
# (needed for as.ts.xts to work)
attr(a1,'.tsp') <- tsp(A1)
attr(a2,'.tsp') <- tsp(A2)

a <- ts.intersect(a1,a2)
```

Comment: Seems the `ts -> xts -> ts` bug still exists. @Joshua do we not have equivalent functions in `xts package` so we donot need to convert back and forth every time we need `ts` functions?